MongoDB.Driver.MongoIncompatibleDriverException: Server reports wire version 4 but this version of the driver requires at least 7
I am trying to use Entity Framework and MongoDB.
This is my docker compose:
services:
  mongo-db:
    container_name: mongo-db
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"

Entity and context:
public class Order
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class OrdersDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : DbContext(options)
{
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().ToCollection("orders");
    }
}

This is how I am trying to use it:
var order = new Order
{
    Id = Helpers.GetNewId(),
    Name = "Some order"
};

var mongoClient = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
var dbContextOptions =
    new DbContextOptionsBuilder<OrdersDbContext>().UseMongoDB(mongoClient, "orders");
var ordersDb = new OrdersDbContext(dbContextOptions.Options);
ordersDb.Orders.Add(order);
ordersDb.SaveChanges();

When calling SaveChanges, I get this error:

Unhandled exception. MongoDB.Driver.MongoIncompatibleDriverException: Server at localhost:27017 reports wire version 4, but this version of the driver requires at least 7 (MongoDB 4.0.0).
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoIncompatibleDriverException.ThrowIfNotSupported(ClusterDescription description)
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.SelectServerHelper.SelectServer()
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.SelectServer(IServerSelector selector, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.IClusterExtensions.SelectServerAndPinIfNeeded(IClusterInternal cluster, ICoreSessionHandle session, IServerSelector selector, IReadOnlyCollection1 deprioritizedServers, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Bindings.WritableServerBinding.GetWriteChannelSource(IReadOnlyCollection1 deprioritizedServers, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Bindings.WritableServerBinding.GetWriteChannelSource(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Bindings.ReadWriteBindingHandle.GetWriteChannelSource(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

That makes no sense to me, since the actual mongodb version in container is 8.0.3. Any ideas how to fix it?

Most-likely, you're wrong, the error says that your server is 3.2 which is very old. You can see it if you run buildInfo command from the shell (like mongosh): (see here)
db.runCommand( { buildInfo: 1 } )


I've got same exception immediately on 3rd line.

This is what I got in the mongo container:
mongod --version
db version v8.0.3

ah, right, you can't send any command because of this, my bad, use mongo shell, see my updated answer

or you can download much older driver version like '2.9'. That command var buildInfo = admin.RunCommand<BsonDocument>("{ buildInfo : 1 }"); will work there

mongod --version db version v8.0.3 - it's strange, I feel like there is some misconfiguration on your side, mostlikely the server you're actually querying is not the same what you call mongod --version command for

is not the same what you call mongod --version command for - so you will see it if you get a server version from buildInfo  result

You were right, actually. It turned out I already had another instance of a very old MongoDB running on this port. And then I added a Docker container which exposes the same port, which is already blocked, so it was inaccessible via this port. Each time I tried to connect to the wrong instance. I wasted so much time on this trap, ohhh
Thank you!
